Is There an Alternative to page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique for Grouping Page Data by Age and Gender?
I've been searching for a metric other than page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique to get page data grouped by age and gender, as this metric is deprecated. However, I haven't found any alternatives. Does anyone know of another option for this purpose?
